# Gatling installation and use

Tags: jmeter, load-testing, stress-testing, gatling

I am new to load testing.
So please help in learning gatling and Apache Jmeter for stress testing.
Please help in installing both on Windows and Linux.
How to implement them in my application?
Which one is better for stress testing?

Comment: Mohit, welcome to SO. You're question is open ended and vague. We can help you with specific problems you're having with any of those tools, but you need to put in some of your own effort to read and learn first - which is why your question was downvoted. [Please see this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

You are asking very generic questions in terms of Stress/Load testing. I think it would be best if you take a look at their documentation then formulate a more specific question.

Installation documentation is best served from the creators of the software.

Implementing these load/stress testing tools into your application isn't really a thing. If you are looking for unit testing (test to utilize in validating your functions/classes/etc work then look at your languages specific go-to libraries - ie. Java is junit/jboss, Nodejs is Karma/Protractor, Python is TestCase/Nose, etc). These tools (jmeter/gatling) are used for stressing your application outside of your build process so they should be treated as end-users (meaning you run the stress testing from remote machines if it is a web service).

Either are best for the right scenario. I think jmeter clusters easier (built-in, where gatling is more manual) but gatling is more programatic and can be manipulated more.

**These are opinions and shouldn't be taken as fact or the best so your milage may vary**

Answer (score 0):

I strongly doubt that you need them both, if you want a piece of advice in regards which one to choose take a look at [Open Source Load Testing Tools: Which One Should You Use?](http://blazemeter.com/blog/open-source-load-testing-tools-which-one-should-you-use) guide.

Once you have clear vision on what tool better suits the needs - you could start ramping up on the selected tool and ask questions in its community communication channels.